# How to use viewpager and tablayout inside a fragment?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I need my app to have bottom bar navigation and swipable tabs. so I need viewpager to swap between fragments nested inside each fragment that is used by the bottom navigation. how do I do this?

Comment: it same as you done in activity (if you already done that) just on difference and that is in fragment you pass `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getSupportFragmentManager()` to your `fragmentPagerAdapter`'s` constructor

Answer (score 1):

First, you create a Fragment that contains ViewPager and TabLayout like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".FragmentThatHasViewPagerAndTabLayout">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then create a Activity which includes FrameLayout (that will be used as fragment container) and BottomNavigation

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="#FFF"
        app:itemTextColor="#FFF"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_navigation"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Snippet code for Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation_view);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                  //Change fragment when select another item in BottomNavigation
            }
        }
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new FragmentThatHasViewPagerAndTabLayout(), "TAG_TO_REUSE_FRAGMENT_AFTER_CONFIG_CHANGES").commit();
}
```

And code in Fragment that contains ViewPager and TabLayout, you just write it like normally do (like having a FragmentPagerAdapter, etc.)